# Automatic Re- Initialization of variables after every iteration

Tags: python, initialization

I am working with multiple input files in a program.
So i wanted the same code to run over all files and give me results. 
For this i was looping the main function which contains many variables (around 50).

Is there an easy way to reinitialize all variables after each iteration so that i don't have to  manually reinitialize all 50 variables after each iteration?
P.S.= By initializing , i mean integers to 0, strings to "" and floats to 0.0

Comment: If you are using around 50 local variables, you should maybe consider using a dictionary or a custom class to handle your data.

Comment: Do you have a loop inside the main function or are you executing it multiple times?  Are the variables local or global?  It would help if you could post some (simplified) code.

Comment: I am executing the main function multiple times. Variables are both local and global.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class so you will create a new object for each iteration.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

a = A()
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is really a way to reset all variables back to 0 or nothing. I think you would have to do it manually like you are doing

but if youre trying to save space in youre iterating function you can use a class to initialize all the variables then call that class in the function youre iterating

but besides that there isnt any kind of python trick that will do it for you

look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543833/how-do-i-clear-all-variables-in-the-middle-of-a-python-script) it says:

> The concept is called [namespace](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) and it's so good, it made it into
>   the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):
>
> `Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!`