# Python equivalent of rm( list = ls() )

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to delete all user defined objects from a python session. Suppose I do the following things.

1) Start Rodeo ( a python GUI )

2) write u = 5

3) So u is an object now.

4) import some packages say

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
```

5) Now I want to clear only these objects :- u, os module, pd module and datetime module.

By 'clear' I mean to say that after clearing if I type u in console, python should not be able to find the object u.

Similarly all commands in pd ( i.e. pandas ) module should be inaccessible.

How to do this ?

Please note that I don't want to delete any builtins ( as described in this question : [How do I clear all variables in the middle of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543833/how-do-i-clear-all-variables-in-the-middle-of-a-python-script) ).

The duplicate question that you are pointing does not answer the question completely. I want to know how to remove only the user defined objects without removing the builtins etc.

The duplicate question gives answer about how to remove the builtins too - which I don't want.

Comment: [What's your X?](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: `locals()` and `globals()` are of data type `dict` for `dictionary`  in python. So please check how to `remove objects from dictionary in python by providing index values` may be for those objects as you don't want to remove the bulletins.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian Note that while modifying `globals` has the effect you'd expect, modifying `locals` is **not** reliable. It sometimes works, *most* of the time it doesn't.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you for this information, I have started learning python. I am a beginner.

Comment: In Ipython I found that the command is  %reset -f