# Is there a way to answer "y" to (or ignore) all y/n prompts?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-prompt

I have a Jupyter notebook that has a lot of large variables, and at one point I want to get rid of all the ones I'm done with. I'm using %reset_selective variablename to clear each one, but there's 60 of these variables and when I run the block that has all 60 prompts, it asks me to enter y/n for every clear.

"Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])?"

Is there a way I can answer "y" for all of them at once, or to skip the prompt altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading from [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.namespace.html#IPython.core.magics.namespace.NamespaceMagics.reset_selective):

> %reset_selective [-f] regex
>
> No action is taken if regex is not included
>
> Options
>   **-f** : force reset without asking for confirmation.

Seems you're able to pass `-f` flag to `%reset_selective` to have it force without asking.

Comment: I did "%reset_selective -f variable_name" without specifying "regex". That worked. Thanks!