# "Wiping the slate clean" in python

Tags: python, del

This should be pretty basic, but I can't find anything on it, so ... In python, if I want to just clear out my whole session and start all over without shutting down and starting over, how do I do it?  I want to delete all objects, class defs, function defs, etc.  A couple of things I have tried that don't work are

```
>>> del(dir())
```

and

```
>>> del(dir()[:])
```

I used to know this, and it's something like this, but I can't remember the command.  I am sure this is dangerous.  I promise I will use it only for good.

Comment: You can't. The imports will hang around

Comment: Guess you could create a backup of `globals()` at the beginning of the session and then `del` everything from `globals()` that's not in the backup, but... _why_?

Comment: @MadPhysicist there's no way to list the imports? because you can `del` an import.

Comment: "I promise I will use it only for good." What good? Can you clarify the purpose?

Comment: What's wrong with shutting down Python and starting over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but probably not a good idea. See this: [How do I clear all variables in the middle of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543833/how-do-i-clear-all-variables-in-the-middle-of-a-python-script)

It destroys even builtins, so the shell remains kinda broken after that. You can loop over the dir and omit builtins as mentioned, but I don't see why on Earth would i want to do that rather that simply exiting and running python again (`[ctrl]-[d] [up arrow] [enter]`).

Comment: Well done for finding the duplicate, but after you found it, why did you answer the question rather than flag it?