# How to restart the python repl on the fly?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I restart the python repl by exit, then execute the `python` command again. But I am boring now, I would like to know how to restart the python repl on the fly, in other word, do not exit again.

Comment: os.execv should do it.

Comment: What disadvantage does closing and reopening Python have over any other way? Is this not “on the fly” enough?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The REPL is not script, and I do not know is clearing all variables same as restarting the REPL.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I want to get a clean REPL many times, this processes is boring. Not enough.

Comment: @acgtyrant I can assure you that no other solution will be as fast as hitting ‹Ctrl›-‹D›, followed by ‹up-arrow› and ‹return›. Because that’s all it takes to restart Python. — Furthermore, if you need to clear your REPL very often this suggests that you’re doing something you’re not supposed to do: write reproducible scripts with functions etc. instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It is fast, but `%reset` is better that it will not produce too many promot as `<Ctrl>-<D>, python`. I want to play the Tensor from PyTorch, it can not be managed as the reproducible script.

Comment: [%reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543840/1546088) from [How do I clear all variables in the middle of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543833/how-do-i-clear-all-variables-in-the-middle-of-a-python-script) solve my problem now.